# Site not loading properly on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile-website

I am having issues trying to load my site, http://www.internhacks.io/, on any mobile browser. 
The project can be found [here](https://github.com/InternHacks/InternHacks.github.io) on Github.

I have tested the site on mobile using Chrome dev tools, and everything loads fine/acts responsively.

However, when testing the site on my actual phone, sometimes the site does not load at all, sometimes only partially.

Note: the apply button is not meant to do anything yet

I think it may have to do with having a large image as the background. Should I be serving a smaller version if detecting the window is smaller? **The img height is set to 100vh.**

If anyone knows what might be causing this, or knows of a better way to debug the site on mobile than in Chrome dev tools, please let me know!

Comment: The site loads on my iPhone 6, but the apply button does nothing.

Comment: I just tried on my iphone 4s, and it loads the golden gate bridge picture but it is extremely zoomed in and covers the entire page, likely covering up everything else you have. It is the only thing to load aside from the header info(title, dates, apply button).

Answer (score 0):

I use Opera mini to test mobile devices (aka android) with various screen resolutions.

"height is set to 100vh" huh? never saw that one before.  To fit graphics within space available, avoid fixed sizes (aka 100px) and I use relative width:xx%

YES, it's wasteful to send large graphics to a mobile device and from the server, you need to send some xxx-low-res.img instead

it's helpful to load JS scripts into a   section to allow all objects to be loaded first.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main issues is that the big images should use smaller, light-weight pictures instead since it'll speed up the resize process when rendering on the phone. Other than that, you want to stick away from, as @jobeard mentioned, from using fixed sizes like the 100vh and use a relative width such as 10%.